# Is there a way with Hasura to do a mutation based on the result of a query, within the same GraphQL call (Hasura transaction)?

Tags: hasura

I tried to search for an example but, I presume it's not doable. I am looking to hopefully be proven wrong or to find an official confirmation that it's not doable.

Before using Hasura, I was doing [transactional SQL queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html) that ensured that data was kept consistent.

For example, I would like to create a password reset token if a user requests it, only if the user can be found using an email address. Right now, I have to do 2 queries:

- Try to find a user with the specified email address
- Insert and assign the token to this user id

In that case, it's not too bad, but now if I want to consume that token, I have to do 3 queries:

- Find the valid token
- Change the password to the user associated with that token
- Delete the token

Obviously, if something goes wrong and the token is not deleted, this could be an issue - so I would be curious to see if there would be ways to merge these queries/mutations into transactions.

Comment: There is no way "to do a mutation based on the result of a query, within the same GraphQL call" in Hasura natively. However, you could either make a [SQL function](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/custom-functions/) or use [Event Triggers](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/event-triggers/index/) to orchestrate your cleanup events.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'm not sure how I could use functions or triggers to solve the example I was mentioning. I considered using functions for another problem I ended up having to find another solution due to the constraints around functions

Comment: I guess you can do with just the mutation with where clause. You can 'insert and assign the token where user exists with that email address' returning count or something to let you know email was found and token was assigned.

Comment: for consuming token, you can have two mutations in one call. first mutation to change the password and another one to delete the token. If either of them failed nothing gets commited.

Comment: Do you have example of how to do this? For the first query I need to assign the user ID to the token if it exists.... and the second query you are talking about some sort of transaction? How do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research here is what I found:

For the first example:

> - Try to find a user with the specified email address
> - Insert and assign the token to this user id

**There are no solutions for this today** and as answered by [@damel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74693705/3764048), there is an ongoing RFC to support nested mutations: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1573#issuecomment-1338057350

Hopefully, this feature will be out soon, but in the meantime, for most cases, it's not such a big deal to have multiple queries as it is possible to catch errors on the first query.

For the second example:

> - Find the valid token
> - Change the password to the user associated with that token
> - Delete the token

When sending multiple mutations in the same query, **Hasura treats them as a transaction** as [announced in 2020](https://twitter.com/hasurahq/status/1261214871510802432?lang=en).

Of course, it would be nice to do this in the same query (similar to the first example) but since there is a transaction on the mutation, for this case it's still not a problem.

I am sure there are probably cases where this can become a problem but I am not exposed to them right now. Nevertheless, it would be great if the RFC makes it to production, giving more options to Hasura users.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like supporting nested updates would solve this problem for you with the least amount of effort. We are working on a rfc for the feature and hope to start development soon. Please follow this Github issue on our community for future updates.
https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1573

This comment outlines the current scope of the proposed feature. The rfc will provide a more complete explanation.
https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1573#issuecomment-1338057350

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for - I'll write up a summary of my findings to my original question which hopefully can help more people since I did find solution to the mutation part

Answer (score 0):

You can apply changes to rows that you filter by certain criteria. Here is a sample mutation:

```
mutation PasswordUpdate($id: uuid!, $token: String!, $new_password: String!) {
  update_user(
    where: {id: {_eq: $id}, token: {_eq: $token}}
    _set: {token: null, password: $new_password}
  ) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

That query deletes the token and sets a password for all users (hopefully just one) that have the token assigned.

Comment: Yes, that works if they are on the same table. I realize my question was not super precise, but I will try to provide more details about a solution I found. I learned that Hasura do process multi-mutation requests as transactions.

Comment: You should be able to use conditions on related tables as well.

Comment: Do you have example of running a query before a mutation where a field from the query is used in the mutation? I don't think this part is feasible

Comment: Before the mutation is not possible. However, if you want your business logic to update fields of tables with values that depend on query results then your data schema seems to be flawed and could be improved upon.